# 4-way Venn Diagram in R?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to make an 4-Way Venn Diagram in R.
I have this data which I want to put in the diagram:

[image]

Can anyone give me a suggestion how to do it? I try to use the function vennDiagram() but that does not work, because it is a 4way diagram.

I am also trying  to use the package VennDiagram, but is really confusing the way the data is "allocated" to the right place in the diagram. I am using this code:

```
library (VennDiagram)
venn.diagram(
    x=list(
    I=c(1:18,19:31,32:119,125:129,130:192,193:144,145:326,327:373),
    VI=c(516:542,510:515,420:497,498:509,145:326,327:373,130:192,193:144),
    II=c(19:31,32:119,145:326,327:373,374:378,378:419,420:497,498:509),
    III=c(506:509,378:419,32:119,125:129,130:192,145:326,420:497,510:515)
    ),
    filename = "4Way_Venn.tiff",
    col = "black",
    lty = "dotted",
    lwd = 4,
    fill = c("cornflowerblue", "green", "yellow", "darkorchid1"),
    alpha = 0.50,
    label.col = c("orange", "white", "darkorchid4", "white", "white", "white", 
                  "white", "white", "darkblue", "white", "white", "white", 
                  "white", "darkgreen", "white"),
    cex = 2.5,
    fontfamily = "serif",
    fontface = "bold",
    cat.col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "darkorchid4"),
    cat.cex = 2.5,
    cat.fontfamily = "serif"
    );
```

Can anyone help me? maybe with an easier solution then the one using the VennDiagram package.

Comment: Doesn't Vennerable for R support this? I wrote a solution using Python and gnuplot. Happy to share.

Answer (score 4):

I might be missing the point here but I am not sure how do you want to use those 'counts' in making your venn diagram? From the columns 'c1' to 'c4' you can very easily make venn diagram using [venneuler](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/venneuler/index.html) package:

```
require(venneuler)
#here I replicate your data
#because it's repeatable, you can use `rep` function to generate it
c1 <- rep(c(0,1),each=8)
c2 <- rep(c(0,1),each=4,times=2)
c3 <- rep(c(0,1),each=2,times=4)
c4 <- rep(c(0,1),times=8)
#put your data into matrix
m <- as.matrix(data.frame(C1=c1,C2=c2,C3=c3,C4=c4))
#plot it
v = venneuler(m)
plot(v)
```

[image]

Comment: The Counts is the number of times that each case occur,  it is a summary of the data, and it should be in the diagram. For example there are 26 times in the data were all the c1,c2,c3 and c4 have  the value 0

Comment: @Peiska: Ok I see what you mean mate. Will try to revise it when I have more time.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem but perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638610/how-to-draw-venn-diagram-using-6-sets/31148761#31148761 will help.

Answer (score 3):

Just be careful:  I tried building 4 (and higher)-way Venn diagrams in a couple packages which supported such capability, and in at least one case the subspaces were not correctly drawn.  A subset, for example, which was entirely contained in another was drawn with some of its area extending outside the parent subset.   Unfortunately I don't recall which package did that.
So, my answer is:  try `venneuler` as GOA said, try `require(sos); ???venn` , and be sure to test each package carefully to be sure it's rendering the intersections 
correctly.

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of the nVennR package (0.2.0), you can do it in two ways:

1) From the code you provided,

```
myV <- plotVenn(list(I=c(1:18,19:31,32:119,125:129,130:192,193:144,145:326,327:373), 
IV=c(516:542,510:515,420:497,498:509,145:326,327:373,130:192,193:144), 
II=c(19:31,32:119,145:326,327:373,374:378,378:419,420:497,498:509), 
III=c(506:509,378:419,32:119,125:129,130:192,145:326,420:497,510:515)),
setColors = c("cornflowerblue", "green", "yellow", "darkorchid1"), borderWidth=3, opacity=0.2)
```

[image: Result]

2) Directly from the first listing,

```
myV2 <- createVennObj(nSets = 4, sNames = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"), sSizes = c(26, 27, 4, 6, 5, 12, 42, 78, 18, 52, 4, 63, 13, 47, 88, 182))
myV2 <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV2)
```

[image: Result2]

One of the advantages of the first approach is that the elements in each region can be queried:

```
getVennRegion(myV, c("I", "III"))
[1] 125 126 127 128 129
```

Answer (score 0):

The VennDiagram package has a function for 4 way Venn, that is draw.quad.venn() function:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf