# Venn Diagram with 5 variable in R

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I am trying to create a diagram showing variable overlap. For less than 4 group Venn diagram looks like a good choice, however I am not able to use the 'venndiagram' package as it limits the number of variables.I had something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3ASymmetrical_5-set_Venn_diagram.svg) in mind. 
Here is how my data looks like.

```
          **Groups                  Count**

            None                    151
               A                    121
               B                    108
               D                    4
               E    D                172
               C    D               1
               C    E   D           3
               A    D               6
               A    E   D           129
               A    C   D           3
               A    C   D   E       7
               B    D               7
               B    E   D           121
               B    C   D           6
               B    C   E   D       15
               B    A               153
               B    A   D           32
               B    A   E   D       200
               B    A   C           5
               B    A   C   D       4
               B    A   C   E   D   44
```

We can ignore the "None" class if it makes it easy.
Any help in plotting this on a Venn diagram or other appropriate plot would be great.

Comment: The `gplots` package has venn diagram upto 5 sets, which includes your case. Case in point: last page of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/vignettes/venn.pdf has a venn diagram for 5 set.

Comment: It appears to not have any colour, if that's a area of concern.

Comment: previous discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638610/how-to-draw-venn-diagram-using-6-sets/30686004#30686004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to draw Venn Diagram using 6 sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638610/how-to-draw-venn-diagram-using-6-sets)

Answer (score 1):

In case you may find it interesting, you can use my `nVennR` package to build a quasi-proportional diagram. From your data,

```
library(nVennR)
myV <- createVennObj(nSets = 5, sNames = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("A"), 121)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B"), 108)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("D"), 4)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("E", "D"), 172)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("C", "D"), 1)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("C", "E", "D"), 3)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("A", "D"), 6)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("A", "E", "D"), 129)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("A", "C", "D"), 3)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("A", "C", "D", "E"), 7)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "D"), 7)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "E", "D"), 121)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "C", "D"), 6)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "C", "E", "D"), 15)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "A"), 153)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "A", "D"), 32)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "A", "E", "D"), 200)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "A", "C"), 5)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "A", "C", "D"), 4)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c("B", "A", "C", "E", "D"), 44)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
```

The last command is duplicated on purpose, so that the result is compacted. You can find details and other faster forms of input in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html). The result:

[image]