# How to make a venn diagram with VennDiagram () for 4 sets in R

Tags: r

I refer to the website (https://r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm) to learn how to draw a venn diagram.
I would like to make it with 4 sets.
Where should I update/revise in the given data code on the website?

[I'd like to see this kind of figure in the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTI6N.png)

Comment: This question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111430/4-way-venn-diagram-in-r

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the manual, it appears you want `draw.quad.venn`

```r
library(VennDiagram)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: futile.logger

draw.quad.venn(72, 86, 50, 52, 44, 27, 32, 38, 32, 20, 18, 17, 11, 13, 6,
  category = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"),
  fill = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"),
  cex = 2,
  cat.cex = 2,
  cat.col = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue")
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**

The OP apparently prefers circles to ellipses, which neither `VennDiagram` nor `ggVenn` seem to provide. In this case, we probably just need the graphics primitives, such as

```r
library(grid)

cg <- circleGrob(c(0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6), c(0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6),
                 r = 0.25, gp = gpar(fill = NA, lwd = 2))

titles <- textGrob( c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"),
                   c(0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9), c(0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9),
                   gp = gpar(cex = 2))

values <- textGrob(c(9, 14, 1, 3, 15, 8, 2, 4, 12, 11, 5, 7, 6),
                   c(0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.41, 0.59, 
                     0.41, 0.59, 0.5),
                   c(0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.41, 0.41,
                     0.59, 0.59, 0.5))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(cg)
grid.draw(titles)
grid.draw(values)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this design was what I've seen on google. However, I don't like the curved type, but just I want perfect circles. That's why I'm struggling with the codes.

Comment: This is what this package (and the ggVenn package) produces for a 4 category Venn. If you want something different you may need to draw it manually using graphics primitives. This is certainly possible, but it's a pain.

Comment: @dbfk2000 I have put some effort in to generate the necessary graphics primitives - see my update